# Object expected error

Tags: javascript, jquery

My site is working perfectly in all browsers except the IE.
The error box is prompted when the page is load in IE with the error msg below:
Line: 227
Error: Object expected

when i start debugging, the error is from here below at the first line.

```
$().ready(function()
{
    // Hide all elements with .hideOnSubmit class when parent form is submit
    $('form').submit(function()
    {
        $(this).find('.hideOnSubmit').hide();
    });
});
```

Can anyone advice? it is really annoying to prompt that message on every page

============== EDIT ===============
I have tried the advice below

```
$(document).ready(function($)
{
    // Hide all elements with .hideOnSubmit class when parent form is submit
    $('form').submit(function()
    {
        $(this).find('.hideOnSubmit').hide();
    });
});
```

OR

```
jquery(function($)
{
    // Hide all elements with .hideOnSubmit class when parent form is submit
    $('form').submit(function()
    {
        $(this).find('.hideOnSubmit').hide();
    });
});
```

But both also give me the same error.

Comment: looks like you are getting the error on fb connect.

Comment: Yup, there are 2 errors. Ignore the URI: http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1  error.

Comment: are you using prestashop? and the latest stable version?

Comment: Yes i am using prestashop 1.4.4 latest version.

Comment: Can i just remove that function?

Answer (score 4):

Either use

```
$(document).ready(function() { … } );
```

or

```
jQuery(function($) { … } );
```

Comment: +1 Spot on! I would add though the reason for the error is the `$()`.

Comment: Correct! :) $() should return either null or does not work at all if I'm right, and using the ready function on nothing does not sound likely to work.

Comment: Hi i have tried the code you mentioned, but it is still giving me same error. Please check the edited post above.

Comment: Your code looks totally correct to me. Do you have any other javascript code before that line?

Comment: No, there is no more code. The below is the original code from Prestashop 1.4.4 tools.js `function isArrowKey(k_ev)
{
 var unicode=k_ev.keyCode? k_ev.keyCode : k_ev.charCode;
 if (unicode >= 37 && unicode <= 40)
  return true;

}

//On dom ready
$().ready(function()
{
 // Hide all elements with .hideOnSubmit class when parent form is submit
 $('form').submit(function()
 {
  $(this).find('.hideOnSubmit').hide();
 });
});`

Comment: Ah ok, you should've mentioned that it's a third-party library and not your own code. So it's less likely that it contains errors. Sorry, I'm out of ideas here.

Comment: @belinq let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2758/discussion-between-sebastian-wramba-and-belinq)

Answer (score 0):

Does your form have a control with a name or id iof *submit*? If so, it is shaddowing the submit method of the form.

Change it to something else, like "submitButton", or if you don't need to reference it or post it with the form, don't give it a name or id at all.

Comment: Ok, this sound abit confuse for me as i do not know which form is actually using that $().ready function from the tools.js.

Comment: Form controls with names or ids are made available as named properties of the form they are in. Just make sure you don't have any form controls with names or ids that are the same as properties or methods of the [HTMLFormElement interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-40002357).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        var elm = $(this).find('.hideOnSubmit');
        if (elm.length) {
            elm.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It don work either by showing the same error :(

Comment: its `jQuery` not `jquery` doesn't seem like a big difference but it is.

Comment: I am sorry, the error msg is still keep showing on every page when it loads. Can i remove that function instead?